# Inner Join two tables and make only latest record appear (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two parent tables which create a composite inside the child table (compresults)

I want to get the most recent record (only 1) for each athlete

I know the answer is along the lines of selecting the competition with the max date and only displaying it that way, however i have been trying to do this but i cannot get the formatting right

Parent Table (athletes)

`+---------+-------+
| athlete | name  |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | James |
| 2       | Gemma |
+---------+-------+`

Parent Table (competitions)

`+-----+----------+----------+
| cid | compname | compdate |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 1   | Comp A   | 2015     |
| 2   | Comp B   | 2014     |
+-----+----------+----------+`

Child Table (compresults)

`+---------+-----+--------+
| athlete | cid | result |
+---------+-----+--------+
| 1       | 1   | 500    |
| 1       | 2   | 550    |
| 2       | 2   | 450    |
+---------+-----+--------+`

EXPECTED RESULT:

`+-------+----------+--------+
| name  | compname | result |
+-------+----------+--------+
| James | Comp A   | 500    |
| Gemma | Comp B   | 450    |
+-------+----------+--------+`

Any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are 2 different products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this receives the result you're after.

```
SELECT a.`name`, b.`compname`, c.`result`
FROM `compresults` c
INNER JOIN `competitions` b ON b.cid = c.cid
INNER JOIN `athletes` a ON c.`athlete` = a.`athlete`
WHERE b.`compdate` = (
                                    SELECT co.`compdate` 
                                    FROM `competitions` co INNER JOIN `compresults` cr ON cr.`cid` = co.`cid` 
                                    WHERE cr.`athlete` = a.`athlete`
                                    ORDER BY co.`compdate` DESC LIMIT 1
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
select b.name,c.compname,a.result from compresults a left join athletes 
b on (a.athlete)=b.athlete
left join competitions c on (a.cid)=c.cid
```

Comment: This query does not provide the info OP is after. He wants the a single, most recent competition record for each athlete, if I understood correctly. This query pulls multiple records, not filtering out any based on how recent they are. It's a good go, but you might wanna give it another shot.